# Order of colors chosen in flot chart

Tags: javascript, flot

I am trying to add custom array of colors to the flot input. But when I try to draw multiple graphs in same page. Some graphs doesnt take the input color array and goes with the default set of colors. The below are the options used, where `colorPalette` is the custom color array used. Any idea when the flot rejects input color array and when it takes.

```
var options = {
    colors: colorPalette,
    legend: {
        show: true,
        margin: 10,
        backgroundOpacity: 0.5,
        position: 'nw'
    },
    yaxes: [
        {
            min: 0,
            labelWidth : yAxisLabelWidth
        },
        {
            alignTicksWithAxis: 1,
            position: 'right',
            min: 0,
            labelWidth : yAxisLabelWidth
        }
    ],
    xaxis: {
        mode: "time",
        tickLength: 0
    },

    grid: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: "#cccccc",
        labelMargin: 10,
        hoverable: true,
        mouseActiveRadius: 8
    },
    stack: null,
    bars: {
        show: true,
        align: 'center',
        lineWidth: 1
    },
    multiplebars: true

};
```

Comment: Try to build a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) which reproduces your problem.

Comment: Check that `colorPallete` has what you need. It could be that the array has less colors than you have series.

Comment: You'll need to show us how you're generating the colorPalette.  As @Raidri suggested, showing us a demo would greatly help.